# how to set the first color of the list in the sprite

Tags: unity, c#, sprites

```
public List<SpriteRenderer> spritebox = new List<SpriteRenderer>();
public List<Color> colorbox = new List<Color>();

void Start() {
    var renderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    colorbox.Add(renderer.color);//I did so, except that it sends the color of the sprite to the list and in the last slot

    spritebox = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    colorbox = spritebox.color;//I did that too but it did not work

}
```

I'm trying to make the first color of the list in case the element 0 send the color to the sprite,would have any tips to help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In arrays and C# lists (which are wrappers for arrays that allow dynamic resizing) you should access elements by index in square brackets.

Examples:

This will get the first color from `colorbox` and store it in variable `color`:
`Color color = colorbox[0];`

This will assign color `color` to the first `SpriteRenderer` from `spritebox`:
`spritebox[0].color = color;`

You can put a variable or an expression inside brackets.